# Twitter API getJSON for Status ID Meta -- Response Empty!

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, getjson

There are some similar posts on SO about this topic but they are all dealing with search and I am trying to do something different.  I have tried to apply some of the logic in answers to other questions here but w/o success.  Essentially I just want users to be able to enter a status update ID into a text field, hit a button then display all meta data associated with that tweet.  If I leave the callback=? part off of the URL string I get a response back but it's empty, which is obviously due to the security restrictions put in place by the Twitter API.

Here is what I am working with currently:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.twitter.com/statuses/show/73051651728084992.json?callback=?", 
function(Data) 
{ 
  if(Data.length)
  {
    var Content = "";
    $.each(Data, function(i, Row)
    {
      alert("We Have Data");
      Content += Row;
    });
    $("#Result").append(Row);
  }
  else
    alert("No Result for that ID!");
})
```

Which comes back w/ no data, yet the request does come back w/ a 200 HTTP response.  Obviously I am missing something as far as the callback goes, I am just not sure what. Just as a crude proof of concept I was going to output all of the data to the Result div and pretty it up later.  Obviously first things first I need to actually have some data to work with!

What am I missing?

Comment: You should update your URL to the supported [GET statuses/show](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id) endpoint. `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/73051651728084992.json`

Comment: Abraham: That is actually the URL I had started out with and I thought perhaps it was part of the problem.  I have actually already updated my code to point to the proper API endpoint.  Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `?callback=?` from the url and try again. You are asking Twitter's api to wrap the response in a callback `?` which would result in invalid JSON. Also, whenever in doubt, load the url manually in your browser to examine whether the response is correctly formatted.

Also, change to this, since `$.getJSON()` returns an Object, not a string:

```
if (Data) {
    var Content = "";
    ..
}
```

Comment: As I mention in the post if I leave the ?callback=? I get the 200 HTTP response but still an empty result.  If I hit the URL from a browser I get the .json file which is exactly what I want.

Comment: Sorry for the partial response -- I just verified the rest of your code and updated my answer.

Comment: Cool, made a couple tweaks and now have data coming back.  Just need to come up w/ a parsing routine and should be in good shape.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad you're making progress!